# How to get the original binary value back to string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My SQL query returns the value as below

```
Declare @ID varbinary(18)
Declare @newReturnID NvarCHAR(100) 
set @ID =  CONVERT(VARBINARY(18), CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), CONVERT(VARBINARY(2), 41)) +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), NEWID())) 
select  @ID ID
```

ID(Column name)

0x002936354446393642302D333936312D3436

I need to assign an variable as the above value  i am trying to convert into an 
string but i get an different value ?

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    byte[] bytes = (byte[])dr["ID"];
    string strID = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

By my string strID holds different value, not as the above one?

Let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: _"strID holds different value"_ - post that string too.

Comment: what's the value in your dr["ID"] and strID?

Comment: my StrID value is :"ACk1MzE4QzFCNC1GOUNCLTQ0"

Comment: Inside sql you see base-16 string, but inside c# you are reading byte array from db and converting to base-64 string. Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: So what needs to be  done ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: i am using Sql server 2012

Comment: First of all, you are using `NEWID()` in your SQL statement, thus you always create a different value. Second, in your C# you are converting to a base64 encoded string. Thus you will never get an identical result for the source string and the base64 encoded string. Third, you seem to have converted a different result when you gave your `strID`. The actual base64 value for `0x002936354446393642302D333936312D3436` would be `ACk2NURGOTZCMC0zOTYxLTQ2`. Fourth, your varbinary starts with 0x00, thus converting it to a string would result in the string starting with the `\0` terminator character.

Comment: i changed it in sql  to send data  as varchar :select convert(varchar(max), @ID, 1) as  ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are converting Bytes to Base64 string while 0x002.. is hex representation fo bytes.

If it's not compulsory to convert string in c# code, try select converting string in SQL select statement.

```
select convert(varchar(max), @ID, 1) as  ID
```

Refer this link ([Binary Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#binary-styles)) for detail for 3rd argument in `Convert`.

**Edit:**

Also, in c# you will need to convert byte array to hex string. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) is answer already available for this to convert byte array to hex string.
One function posting from that link.

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
  StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
  foreach (byte b in ba)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
  return hex.ToString();
}
```